# Отображение размеченного объединения (discriminated unions) в WPF

Tags: wpf, f#

В `WPF` проекте есть размеченное объединение

```
type Level = | Begginer | Intermediate | Advanced | Expert
```

Но при привязки данных

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Level}" />
```

вместо названия выводится полное имя типа

```
Models.Level
```

---

MCVE

---

```
namespace Model

type Level = | Begginer | Intermediate | Advanced | Expert
```

Контекст для данных

```
module SomeContext = 
    open Model
    open Gjallarhorn.Bindable

    let context() = 
        let source = Binding.createSource()
        Binding.constantToView "Level" Advanced source
        source
```

Для упрощения работы добавлены ссылки на следующие библиотеки:

- [FsXaml](http://fsprojects.github.io/FsXaml/)
- [Gjallarhorn](http://reedcopsey.github.io/Gjallarhorn/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того, чтобы получить требуемое отображение нужно явно указать какой результат хотите увидеть.

Если это просто название вариант для размеченного объединения, то первый способ который сразу приходит на ум - переопределение стандартного метода `ToString`.

Пример

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection

type Level = | Begginer | Intermediate | Advanced | Expert   
     with override x.ToString() = 
            let case, _ = FSharpValue.GetUnionFields(x, x.GetType())
            case.Name
```

Здесь используется рефлексия F# типов, а именно функция `GetUnionFields`, которая определяет вариант объединения и связанные поля для объекта. Более подробная информация есть в [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/fsharpvalue.getunionfields-method-%5Bfsharp%5D)

В данном примере варианты тривиальны, поэтому можно было не использовать рефлексию явно, а просто написать

```
with override x.ToString() = sprintf "%A" x
```

В данном случае результат не измениться, но если вариант в размеченном объединении будет со связанными полями, то ожидаемо получите совсем другое отображение.

Второй вариант - использовать конвертер значений, который для простейшего случая будет практически копировать определение для `ToString` выше

```
type DiscriminatedUnionText() =
    interface System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter with
        override this.Convert(value, _, _, _) =
            let case, _ = FSharpValue.GetUnionFields(value, value.GetType())
            case.Name |> box     
        override this.ConvertBack(_, _, _, _) =
            NotImplementedException() |> raise
```

Но, учитывая, что в проекте используется `FsXAML`, то определить конвертер можно более простым способом, использовав для этого класс `ConverterBase` :

```
open FsXaml

type DiscriminatedUnion() =
     inherit ConverterBase
        (fun value _ _ _ ->
            let case, _ = FSharpValue.GetUnionFields(value, value.GetType())
            case.Name |> box)
```